# How to get the native screen resolution of external monitor

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am testing my android application using midnight streaming box (Android 4.0.4) and external monitor having 1080p resolution. When I request the width and height of the screen for rendering video, I got only 1280x720 instead of 1920x1080. Here is the code that I used.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
```

By the way, the following code had been added to the corresponding activity to get the full screen without title bar.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I am pretty sure that the resolution at my monitor is set to 1080p. Any idea why Android is using only 720p ?

Answer (score 2):

> When I request the width and height of the screen for rendering video, I got only 1280x720 instead of 1920x1080.

That is because your phone (or whatever a "midnight streaming box" is) will be displaying 1280x720 on the external display.

> Any idea why Android is using only 720p ?

Devices that supported external displays via HDMI between Android 3.0 and Android 4.2 would do one of two things:

1. Offer no means whatsoever for third-party apps to project to the display, or
2. Use the device's native resolution, or something close to it

For example, connecting a WXGA800 tablet to a 1080p-capable display would result in a 720p image, as Android would expand the size of the system bar to 80px and mirror everything above that to the monitor. The resolution of the display was not the constraint -- the resolution of the device was.

Hence, 720p is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Just FYI, this isn't necessarily an "external" display as the device in question has no built-in display. Whatever gets plugged in is the display, period, though it's unclear without research/testing if applications can discover that it is external, or if it is presented as if it were the built-in display.

Answer (score 2):

After editing the /system/build.props file, I am getting 1080p resolution from my midnight Android streaming box. Of course, I need to have root access to the file system for editing.

Set width and height to be 1920 and 1080 as follow.

```
const.window.w=1920
const.window.h=1080
```

And then comment out the following line.

```
#ro.platform.has.1080scale=2
```

Please refer to the following post for more details.
http://androidtvbox.us/topic/maximum-resolution-of-hdmi-output/#post-4253